# VS Code ctrl+click behaviour on file explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I updated VSCode and the behaviour of ctrl+click on file explorer changed.

Before it opens the file in a splited view, now opens the file on current window.

How can I enable the old behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [v1.20 Release Notes MultiSelect](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_multi-select-in-the-explorer)

> Clicking with the Ctrl/Cmd key pressed will no longer open an editor
>   to the side because this key is now used to add more items to the
>   multi-selection. A new setting, workbench.list.multiSelectModifier,
>   allows you to change back to the old behavior by setting it to
>   "workbench.list.multiSelectModifier": "alt". With this setting, you
>   use the Alt key to add items to the selection.

So setting to "alt" will return the old behavior.

```
  "workbench.list.multiSelectModifier": "alt"
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> is now bound by default to open in split view. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> - to multi-select in tree.

You can change it though:

```json
"workbench.list.multiSelectModifier": "alt",
```